# Phpexcel calling insertNewRowBefore more than once (multiple times) gives "Invalid cell coordinate i$1" exception

Tags: php, laravel-4, phpexcel

When I try PhpExcel insertNewRowBefore for the first time it runs flawlessly but whenever I need to call it more than once it gives me exception

```
Invalid cell coordinate i$1
```

even I have used the same row number but still get the same error.

```
$objWorksheet->insertNewRowBefore(5, 1);
$objWorksheet->insertNewRowBefore(5, 2);
```

I've accessed the rows after the insert new row function they are working as expected eg inserting 2 rows and after getting i+2 gives expected output. but calling insertNewRowBefore gives the exception..

I am using Laravel 4.2 I've included
"phpoffice/phpexcel": "1.8.0"
which is working fine..

and I am using .xlsx file and using PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName); to read file.

Need help.. thanks

Comment: Without knowing anything more, it's impossible to say.... but it's an expensive operation to use more than once if you can avoid it, so a real world example where you need to do so would perhaps help understand the problem

Comment: I am creating an app that takes a template in excel which is a schema that has tags in it.
eg
%g%
%i% %itemName% %itemGroup%
%g%
this is a simple item in a group and I have multiple groups 
what i need to do is I need to read item (%i%) and replace the item with its values and there could be multiple groups so i need to call insert many times in a worksheet

Comment: @MarkBaker can you explain this please.

Comment: No I can't, not without creating a test to replicate the problem; and that's very difficult to do without an example (even something as simple as a stack dump would help, or knowing what line in which file the error occurs), or a lot of trial and error to figure out what could possibly cause the problem.... and I already have tests that use multiple calls to `insertNewRowBefore()` and that run without problem, so that doesn't highlight any issues in and of itself

Comment: $inputFileName = public_path().'/PrintableTemplates&Results.xlsx';
$sheet = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
$objWorksheet = $sheet->getActiveSheet();
$objWorksheet->insertNewRowBefore(5, 1);
$objWorksheet->insertNewRowBefore(2, 2);

Exception

I've posted the trace above with my question

Comment: @MarkBaker I cant post pictures of the trace I am sharing the stack trace in comment

Comment: PHPExcel_Exception
Invalid cell coordinate i$1

Exception trace:
throw new PHPExcel_Exception('Invalid cell coordinate '.$pCoordinateString);

file: 
PHPExcel/Cell.php

Comment: Exception trace:
list($newColumn, $newRow) = PHPExcel_Cell::coordinateFromString( $pCellReference );

file: 
/PHPExcel/ReferenceHelper.php

Comment: Exception trace:
return $this->_updateSingleCellReference($pCellRange, $pBefore, $pNumCols, $pNumRows);

file: 
PHPExcel/ReferenceHelper.php

Comment: exception:
$modified3 = substr($this->updateCellReference($match[3].'$1',$pBefore,$pNumCols,$pNumRows),0,-2);

file:
PHPExcel/ReferenceHelper.php

Comment: exception:
$pBefore, $pNumCols, $pNumRows, $pSheet->getTitle()));   line:454
file:
PHPExcel/ReferenceHelper.php

Comment: exception:
$objReferenceHelper->insertNewBefore('A' . $pBefore, 0, $pNumRows, $this);   line:2004
file:
PHPExcel/Worksheet.php

Comment: exception:
 $objWorksheet->insertNewRowBefore(2, 1);
          (  $objWorksheet->insertNewRowBefore(2, 2);  )<--- highlighted line
file:
test.php

Comment: @MarkBaker I hope you could understand the trace let me know if you need anything else.. Sorry for the inconvenience but i cant post pictures in here.. thanks

Comment: @MarkBaker When i insert two rows in the end like
$objWorksheet->insertNewRowBefore($objWorksheet->getHighestRow()+1, 1);
$objWorksheet->insertNewRowBefore($objWorksheet->getHighestRow()+1, 1);

It doesn't give me an exception but when i do insert in the middle if the sheet it gives me the exception

Comment: It's when it needs to move a specific cell containing a reference to another cell in a formula, and that reference is lower case, but I don't yet have a patch for it

Comment: I couldnt find the exact issue but the issue was occurring due to formula in a cell.. Thanks Mark